# TagHelper specify valid attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am playing around with creating a custom tag helper in MVC 6 / ASP.Net vNext - the taghelper works fine, **however is there a way to specify valid asp- attributes to use with the tag so they appear in intellisense?** For example, I want **asp-ajax** and **asp-onsuccess** to come up in the intellisense list when adding a tag in the view that matches the criteria for my taghelper below:

```
[TargetElement("form", Attributes = AjaxForm)]
public class UnobtrusiveFormTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string AjaxForm = "asp-ajax";

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        base.Process(context, output);

        output.Attributes.Add("data-ajax", true);
        output.Attributes.Add("data-onsuccess", context.AllAttributes["asp-onsuccess"]);

    }

}
```

Usage:

```
<form asp-ajax="true" asp-onsuccess="dothis();">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With what you have right now (`Attributes = AjaxForm`) you'll get `asp-ajax` in your IntelliSense for `form` tags. If you want to also provide `data-onsuccess` in IntelliSense on `form` tags you can add another `TargetElement` attribute, aka: `[TargetElement("form", Attributes = "asp-onsuccess")]`. I want to note, that adding `Attributes` like this only controls "when" the `TagHelper` runs. Think of it like saying: Only run when these attributes are present on the HTML element.

If you want to consume the values of the attributes AND provide IntelliSense you can add properties:

```
public bool AspAjax { get; set; }

[HtmlAttributeName("asp-onsuccess")]
public string AspOnSuccess { get; set; }
```

This approach doesn't control "when" the `TagHelper` runs but provides a way to input information into your `TagHelper`. It will enable you to take their values and add them as `data-` attributes. Note that by adding `AspAjax`/`AspOnSuccess` as properties their values no longer exist on `output.Attributes` so you don't need to remove them.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that was bang on what I needed :)